# Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 6 in

Tags: php, function

i have some code,

```
if(logged_in() == true){ 
$website_id = (INT)$_GET['id'];
$addedById  = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `websites` WHERE `id` = '$website_id'"), 0);
$q = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `phone` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '$addedById'"));
$result       = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `websites` WHERE `id` = '$website_id'");
echo $q['phone'];
 }
else{ 
echo' please logged_in'; 
 }
```

and returns the error " Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result"

in the in the row

```
$addedById  = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `websites` WHERE `id` = '$website_id'"), 0);
```

I tried several options to fix the problem, and nothing, how should I fix it?

Comment: Are there any results for that WHERE clause? This suggests you have 0 rows returned

Comment: Yes, i solved,  the problem was in WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the code and check the result of the query..

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT user_id FROM websites WHERE id = '.$website_id);
if (!$result || empty($result)) {
    echo 'Could not query:' . mysql_error();
}
echo mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Here's your code with some changes (not a good code, but try it out):

```
if(logged_in() == true){ 
    $website_id = (INT)$_GET['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM websites WHERE id = " . $website_id);
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $addedById = mysql_result($result, 0);

        $query_user = mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM users WHERE user_id = " . $addedById);
        $result_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_user);
        if (!empty($result_user) {
            echo $result_user[0]['phone'];
        }
    }
 } else { 
    echo' please logged_in'; 
 }
```

But you should not use this mysql functions anymore, they are deprecated.
Use PDO or MySQLi.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: yes i tried, in this case the error occurs in the row : `$addedById = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM websites WHERE id = '$website_id'"), 0);` and `echo mysql_result($result, 0);`

Comment: yes, i tried more option for this code(after writing your code), but remains the old error :  `$addedById = mysql_result($result, 0);` already do not know what to do :)